# How to access the Help option in MS Office

Tags: microsoft-office-2016

I have installed **Microsoft Office 2016** on my PC, but the **Help** option appears to not be working or accessible. How do I activate or use the **Help** functionality with Microsoft Office 2016 applications?

Comment: You should be able to repair Office from *Control Panel > Programs and features*.

Comment: Do you mean you cannot click Help option? Or you cannot find the Help option?

Comment: As @Lee notes, please clarify what you mean by "the Help Option" is not working. Use the EDIT button to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Microsoft Office Help functionality

1. Open a Microsoft Word or Excel document or create an empty or blank
   document and then up top above the toolbar area click on the light
   bulb icon.

   [image]
2. Start typing in whatever you need help with and then select the **Get Help on** option from the drop down menu to to see a quick note context menu for the item. If that's not enough then you can select the **More Results for** option to get more detail on the searched criteria.

   [image]
3. If you select the **More Results for** option then you will see a **Help** menu pop up on the left side of the screen at which point you can click on various links it provides on the searched criteria.

   [image]

---

### Making Microsoft Office Help functionality more easily accessible

1. From the upper left side above the toolbar area click on the **Customize Quick Access Toolbar** option, and then select the **More Commands...** option from the dropdown menue.

   [image]
2. From the **Choose command from** option select **All Commands** and then from the commands beneath scroll to find **Help** with the blue question mark icon and highlight it and then press **Add** | **OK**.

   [image]
3. Now you will have a new question mark circle **`?`** button to press in the upper left side area above the toolbar which when selected will open the **Help** search functionality of the Microsoft Office application.

   [image]